Did polls adjust their methodology after overestimating Democrat's shares in the 2016 and 2020 presidential elections in the Rust Belt?
In both the 2016 and 2020 presidential elections, polls generally overestimated Democrat's shares in the Rust Belt. In 2020, Biden won them but still his shares were much lower than what polls predicted especially in the Rust Belt.
But some claim that now polls have adjusted their methods and now the polls must be correct. Is that true? Then what was the problem with those polling methods in 2016 and 2020, and how did they adjust?

"now the polls must be correct" It may only be a wording issue but I strongly doubt anyone makes these claims or if they are don't believe a single word more.

Just keep in mind that many polling orgs made the same claims - of having compensated - in 2020. If you recall, most of them were calling that election as an easy win for Biden and it turned out to be a lot closer than they had projected.  Many of them will have some highly convincing technical verbiage talking up arcane statistical adjustments they've made now, for 2024.  Whether that's true we'll know... November 6th.

FWIW, the polling biases in favor of Democrats in 2020 were pretty much across the board and were even greater in U.S. Senate races than in the Presidential race. AZ and GA were rare exceptions to the general rule. https://washparkprophet.blogspot.com/search?q=2020+election+polling

State by state comparisons of polling v. outcomes on election day in 2020 are in a chart buried in this blog post. https://washparkprophet.blogspot.com/2020/12/the-final-presidential-election-results.html

This article has an overview of the challenges for polling companies and how they are responding. TL;DR randomly calling residential phones doesn't work anymore, but the alternatives bring new and complicated biases.
Polling companies are constantly experimenting with new polling methods while trying to measure their biases and compensate accordingly. https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2023/04/19/how-public-polling-has-changed-in-the-21st-century/

Apparently some pollsters are trying to compensate:

In its post-2020 report, AAPOR cited nonresponse bias as one of the potential reasons for the cycle's larger polling error, possibly because Democrats were systematically more likely to respond to pollsters than Republicans, and because the Republicans who did answer may have differed in important ways from the Republicans who didn't. The 2020 election's record-setting turnout amid the COVID-19 pandemic also complicated pollsters' efforts to get a read on just who was most likely to vote, as states expanded mail-in voting and Trump's presidency likely motivated higher turnout among both supporters and opponents.
In light of all this, some pollsters like SSRS are weighting their sample data this cycle by accounting for respondents' past votes (or at least who they recall voting for) to better ensure that the political makeup of survey samples more closely matches reality. "If there is a nonresponse bias that is specifically tied to your vote choice, it's like the worst kind of nonresponse bias for any survey, right?" McPhee said. "This recalled vote thing is our best way of fixing that. The people that voted for Trump in 2020 and are responding to our surveys at a lower rate than the people that voted for Biden need to be weighted up."

The article then discusses how using questions about past voting can be used as a proxy.
From another piece, SSRS is used by CNN and possibly others. Other changes made seem to include not relying on random dialing as much:

Among public pollsters, CNN made some of the most dramatic changes to its methodology. Mostly abandoning its longstanding process of random-digit phone sampling, the network and its polling vendor SSRS randomly selected street addresses for its national surveys and mailed out solicitations to complete a poll online or by dialing a number.
For much of their state polling — which requires faster turnaround times to poll statewide races like those for governor or Senate — some voters were surveyed off a file of registered voters and contacted either by email or telephone, depending on the best contact information available. Others were added from SSRS’ existing panel of respondents who said they were registered to vote.
The results were remarkable. CNN’s polls correctly identified the winner in eight of the nine major statewide races they surveyed — missing only the Nevada Senate race — and half of the candidate vote shares were accurate within a single percentage point.

Another angle, related to certain impatient Trump/Republican voters:

“Some people will start a poll, they’ll tell you who they’re going to vote for and then they say, ‘I’m done. I don’t want to talk to you anymore. Goodbye,’” Don Levy, director of the Siena College Research Institute, which helps conduct polls for the New York Times, told CNBC. “In 2020 and 2022, we didn’t count those people.”
But this time around, Levy says they are counting the “drop-offs.”
They found that if they had counted those impatient respondents in 2020 and 2022, their poll results would have moved “about a point and a quarter in the Trump direction,” Levy said, eliminating roughly 40% of their error.

How well [all] that will work for the 2024 presidential election is ultimately unknown until after election day, of course.

Great answer. Thank you! Is there a way to tell which pollsters adopted such a correction, and which didn't?

@user1849133: I doubt there's any aggregator that makes this info easy to find. The fairly substantial variation in 'fixes' adopted probably doesn't make any systematization easy either.
